# Pandas - Determining max date for each account in a dataframe

Tags: date, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account':['1234', '1234', '4567', '4567'],
                   'Date':['12/5/2017', '12/5/2017', '12/10/2017', '12/11/2017']})

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df.head()

     Account   Date
0    1234     2017-12-05
1    1234     2017-12-05
2    4567     2017-12-10
3    4567     2017-12-11
```

I would like to add a column called MaxDate which would contain the last date for each account. End result like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account':['1234', '1234', '4567', '4567'],
                   'Date':['12/5/2017', '12/5/2017', '12/10/2017', '12/11/2017'],
                   'MaxDate':['12/5/2017', '12/5/2017', '12/11/2017', '12/11/2017']})

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.MaxDate = pd.to_datetime(df.MaxDate)

df.head()

     Account  Date         MaxDate
0    1234     2017-12-05   2017-12-05
1    1234     2017-12-05   2017-12-05
2    4567     2017-12-10   2017-12-11
3    4567     2017-12-11   2017-12-11
```

I'm not sure if I should be iterating over the dataframe or? Note that the data set can be a million rows so performance is a consideration. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [107]: df['MaxDate'] = df.groupby('Account').Date.transform('max')

In [108]: df
Out[108]:
  Account       Date    MaxDate
0    1234 2017-12-05 2017-12-05
1    1234 2017-12-05 2017-12-05
2    4567 2017-12-10 2017-12-11
3    4567 2017-12-11 2017-12-11
```

or `'last'` depending on your goals

```
df['MaxDate'] = df.groupby('Account').Date.transform('last')
```

Comment: You're quick. I tried this on a larger data set and it works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because @MaxU was too quick with the better answer, here are some alternatives

```
df.join(df.groupby('Account').Date.max().rename('MaxDate'), on='Account')

  Account       Date    MaxDate
0    1234 2017-12-05 2017-12-05
1    1234 2017-12-05 2017-12-05
2    4567 2017-12-10 2017-12-11
3    4567 2017-12-11 2017-12-11
```

Or another way

```
df.assign(MaxDate=df.Account.map(df.groupby('Account').Date.max()))

  Account       Date    MaxDate
0    1234 2017-12-05 2017-12-05
1    1234 2017-12-05 2017-12-05
2    4567 2017-12-10 2017-12-11
3    4567 2017-12-11 2017-12-11
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. These will go into my toolbox.